# HTML5 local session store on link click?

Tags: javascript, html, session

I'm trying to use the HTML5 local session store on a hyperlink click.

But nothing gets stored in the local storage sessions in my code.. the reason I know there is nothing because I'm using FF browser and i have the console open when I click on the link.

this is my simple code:

```
<a onClick="sessionStorage.someKey = 'category 1';" data-fajax="false" href="some-page.html" data-transition="slidefade">Category 1</a>
```

could someone please advise on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work for me take a look at **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6c4q2vux/)** :

```
<a onClick="sessionStorage.someKey = 'category 1'; console.log(sessionStorage.someKey);" data-fajax="false" href="some-page.html" data-transition="slidefade">Category 1</a>
```

I can see `category 1` in my console after click.

Answer (score 1):

Try using following

```
<a onclick="sessionStorage.setItem('key','value')" data-fajax="false" href="some-page.html" data-transition="slidefade">Category 1</a>
```

Where key is the name of your session key and value is the value that you want to store.